# Induction proof with binomials

Tags: induction, binomial-theorem

Prove that for all $n\in\mathbb N^+ $ that

$2n \choose n $ $\ge 2^{2n-1}/ n^{1/2}$

I know that I am suppose to use induction but I am having trouble getting past what I have:

Proof:

Suppose that $p(n) $ : $2n \choose n $ $\ge 2^{2n-1}/ n^{1/2}$

Base case $p(1)$ is clearly true.

Induction: $p(n) \Rightarrow p(n+1)$

$2n+1 \choose n+1 $ = $ 2n \choose n+1$ + $2n \choose n$

By the inductive hypothesis we need to know prove that:

$2n+1 \choose n+1 $ $\ge 2^{2n-1}/ n^{1/2}$ + $2n \choose n$

Is this correct? How do I go about doing this from this point? Can someone provide me with the full proof?

Comment: Isn't $1/n^{-1/2} = \sqrt n$ ?

Comment: Sorry! I corrected it!

Comment: Your next step shouldn't be to talk about $\binom{2n+1}{n+1}$ it should be to talk about $\binom{2(n+1)}{n+1}$ i.e. $\binom{2n+2}{n+1}$

Comment: Ahhhh! Thank you I will try to rework this!

Comment: It will probably help you to note that $\binom{2n+2}{n+1} = \frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!(n+1)!} = \frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)(n+1)}\cdot \binom{2n}{n}$

Answer (score 0):

$ P(n) \implies P(n+1)$ : $$ \binom {2n}{n} > \frac{2^{2n-1}}{\sqrt n}$$ $$\frac{2(2n+1)}{(n+1)} \binom{2n}{n}> \frac{2^{2n}(2n+1)}{(n+1)\sqrt n}$$
But $$ \frac{2^{2n}(2n+1)}{(n+1)\sqrt n} > \frac{2^{2n+1}}{\sqrt {(n+1)}}$$ 
Which is true as can be seen after some algebra and so one has:
$$\binom {2n+2}{n+1} =\frac{2(2n+1)}{(n+1)} \binom{2n}{n}> \frac{2^{2n}(2n+1)}{(n+1)\sqrt n}>\frac{2^{2n+1}}{\sqrt {(n+1)}}$$
As wanted